# Add count and percent above grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add both count and percentage, something like "11 (2%)", above each bar in a grouped barplot? I can only do it for percentage using the code below. Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
print(mtcars %>%
    count(cyl = factor(cyl), gear = factor(gear)) %>%
    mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = pct, fill = gear, label = scales::percent(pct))) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9), vjust = -0.5, size = 3) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank()))
```

[image]

Comment: Try something like `label = paste0(n, " (", scales::percent(pct), ")")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
    count(cyl = factor(cyl), gear = factor(gear)) %>%
    mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = pct, fill = gear, 
               label = paste0(n, "\n(", scales::percent(pct), ")"))) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9), vjust = -0.5, size = 3) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 0.5)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

[image]